# Vuex state in Vue.js computed returning before initialised

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to populate the data of a chart but first I have to get data to populate it. This data is inside my vuex state which uses an api request to get the data. But when I return this state its an empty array. How can I ensure that the data is set before I return it?

my vuex state;

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    boardPosts: [],
    boardColumnData: []
};

const actions = {
    getAllBoardPostData: ({commit}) => {
        function getBoardColumns() {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/summary-board/columns');
        }

        function getBoardPosts() {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/summary-board/posts');
        }

        axios.all([getBoardColumns(), getBoardPosts()])
            .then(axios.spread((columnData, postData) => {
                let rawPosts = postData.data;
                let columns = columnData.data;
                let posts = Array.from({length: columns.length}, ()=> []);

                rawPosts.forEach((post) => {
                    // If column index matches post column index value
                    if(posts[post.column_index]){
                        posts[post.column_index].push(post);
                    }
                });

                columns.forEach((column, index) => {
                    let columnValue = 0;

                    posts[index].forEach((post) => {
                        columnValue += post.annual_value;
                    });

                    column.column_value = columnValue;
                });

                commit('setBoardColumns', columns);
                commit('setBoardPosts', posts);
            }))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setBoardPosts: (state, payload) => {
        state.boardPosts = payload;
    },
    setBoardColumns: (state, payload) => {
        state.boardColumnData = payload;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

in my vue file;

```
export default {
    name: "Doughnut",
    computed: {
        boardColumns() {
            return this.$store.state.Dashboard.boardColumnData;
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.populate();
    },
    methods: {
        populate() {
            console.log(this.boardColumns) 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Make sure the state is initialized before computed properties are accessed, or if you cannot prevent this in the component, make sure the state is initialized before the component is instantiated.

Comment: @EstusFlask and how would I do that?

Comment: With `v-if` or else. Depends on your components.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your problem, you can setup a watcher on a Vuex store getter and perform your task once you get a value.

Define getter as

```
getters: {
    getBoardData: state => state.boardColumnData
}
```

and map your getter and create a watcher as

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getBoardData'])
},
watch: {
    getBoardData: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(to, from) {
            if(to) {
                //handle your changes
                this.populate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you had the action dispatched in the same component, as actions are asynchronous, you could have chained a callback and called `populate()` on completion.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be forgetting to actually dispatch the action to get the data. Try this in your created hook:

```
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('Dashboard', 'getAllBoardPostData');
  this.populate();
}
```

EDIT:

Dispatching the action in another component is okay. In that case, the created hook might be too early in the lifecycle to wait for the data being fetched (since this component doesn't know about the one doing the dispatch), and it only runs once. You could add a watcher to wait for the computed property to change and trigger a side-effect (the populate method).

```
watch: { 
  boardColumns() { 
    this.populate() 
  } 
}
```

Or, if the data is essential to render the component, you could consider using the data to determine a `v-if` in the parent component as @Estus Flask suggested. Depending on how your component is structured in terms of reuse and tight coupling to the store, you could even pass it down as props at that point.

```
// Parent component.vue

<template>
  <Doughnut 
    v-if="boardColumns && boardColumns.length"
    :boardColumns="boardColumns"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Doughnut from './Doughnut.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Doughnut,
  },
  computed: {
    boardColumns() {
      return this.$store.state.Dashboard.boardColumns
    }
  }
}
</script>

// Doughnut.vue

<template>
  <div>
    {{ boardColumns }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Doughnut",
    props: {
      boardColumns: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.populate();
    },
    methods: {
      populate() {
        console.log(this.boardColumns) 
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I see. My issue with this is that another component on the page does this. I can either dispatch from two components on the same page or put the dispatch in the root vue file?

Comment: If another component does this, that should be sufficient. I just didn't see it in your example! 

The created hook might be too early in the lifecycle to wait for the data being fetched (since this component doesn't know about the one doing the dispatch), and it only runs once. You could add a watcher to wait for the computed property to change.

`
watch: {
  boardColumns() { this.populate() }
}
`

Comment: If it's essential to the rendering of your component to have the data, it's probably better practice to use v-if in the parent component as Estus Flask described, so your component is only created once the data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour the component will render before the `Vuex store`. When the computed section will check there won't be data initialised in the `store`.

This could happen when you're using `XHR` request to get the `store` data.

The solution is to use `v-if` condition where the `computed` property is using. In your case you can check

```
v-if = "boardColumns.length>0"
```